# How to call a method from a base class from a method in a derived class?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

I have a base class named sorcerer and I am trying to call the function takeStrength within either the witch or wizard class. How do I do this? I thought it was just `sorcerer::takeStrength(s.sorcerer);` but I can not get it to work. Compile error is invalid use of 'sorcerer::sorcerer' when I try to use `sorcerer::takeStrength(s.sorcerer);` to call takeStrength from within the fight function in the witch class. I figured it was as simple as my syntax for calling the function but after trying different ways I am not sure anymore. Thanks ahead of time for the help!

sorcerer.h:

```
class sorcerer
// models a sorcerer
{
public:
    sorcerer();
    // default constructor, sets name to empty string and strength to 0

    sorcerer(string initName, double initStrength);
    // constructor; sets name to the value of initName; if initStrength > 0
    // strength is set to the value of initStrength, otherwise strength is 
    // set to .1

    string getName();
    // returns the value of name
    // postcondition: the value of name is returned

    double getStrength();
    // returns the value of strength
    // postcondition: the value of strength is returned

    void   takeStrength(sorcerer & s);    
    // takes half the strength of the sorcerer represented by parameter s and 
    // adds it to strength
    // precondition:  s is passed a valid sorcerer object or an object from a  
    //                class that inherits class sorcerer
    // postcondition: strength is increased by half of the strength of the 
    //                object passed to s; the object passed to s has its 
    //                strength reduced by half

    virtual void fight(sorcerer & s) = 0;
    // pure virtual function, makes class sorcerer abstract so that class 
    // sorcerer must be inherited and function fight must be implemented
    //
    // postcondition: a fight has occurred between the calling sorcerer and the
    //                passed sorcerer

private:
    double strength;  // sorcerer strength; 0 or greater
    string name;      // sorcerer name
};
```

witch.h:

```
class witch : public sorcerer
// inherits class sorcerer in order to model a witch
{
public:
    witch();
    // default constructor
//    // calls default constructor of class sorcerer

    witch(string name, double initStrength);
    // constructor
    // calls parametrized constructor of classs sorcerer to initialize strength
    // and name

    void fight(sorcerer & s);
    // fights a sorcerer (an instance object of any class that inherits class 
    // sourcerer) on the witch's home turf
    //
    // postcondition:  A fight has occured between the witch and the passed
    //                 sourcerer.  A tie halts the function.  If there is a 
    //                 winner, the winner's strength is increased by 1/2 of the 
    //                 strength of the loser and the loser's strenght is 
    //                 decreased by half.
};
```

note: wizard.h is the same as witch with a few minor differences

Comment: _"I can not get it to work"_ - So what about it doesn't work? Do you get compile time errors and if so which ones.

Comment: "can not get it to work" is not a problem description. What specifically does that mean? You clearly know, because otherwise you wouldn't feel the need to post here, so there's no reason for you not to explain how it doesn't work in your post. If you want help, you should provide the relevant information that you already have to us to use to do so.

Comment: Please provide a minimal example that *reproduces the problem*.

Comment: Try to replace `s.sorcerer` with just `s`. It seems, you wanted to do type conversion, but it's not necessary and, in your way, incorrect. (`(sorcerer) s` is type conversion, not what you tried to do.)

Comment: @tmricks94: `this*` needs to be `*this` instead. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not show where you are trying to call `takeStrength()` from, but I assume it is inside of your `witch::fight()` and `wizard::fight()` implementations, in which case you would call it like this as needed:

```
void witch::fight(sorcerer & s)
{
    ...
    // taking strength away from the other sorcerer
    // and giving it to this sorcerer
    takeStrength(s);
    ...
    // taking strength away from this sorcerer
    // and giving it to the other sorcerer
    s.takeStrength(*this);
    ...
}
```

```
void wizard::fight(sorcerer & s)
{
    ...
    // taking strength away from the other sorcerer
    // and giving it to this sorcerer
    takeStrength(s);
    ...
    // taking strength away from this sorcerer
    // and giving it to the other sorcerer
    s.takeStrength(*this);
    ...
}
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. thanks a lot man. and by the way I did say which function I was calling from "to call takeStrength from within the fight function ".